# Some characters (like "less or equal than") are not showed when using mpdf

Tags: fonts, mpdf

We use OpenSans font to publish bulletins in HTML thru our server. No problems at all with any character. Entities like "≤" are showed correctly in web browsers, cause they are in that font charset (see HTML screenshot). However, in same server, generated mPDF PDF is missing not even "extended" characters, but the included ones (like "less or equal") in OpenSans (see mPDF screenshot).
There is no difference using CSS or the mPDF default font definition inside PHP coding. Same result. Characters are showed like squares.

Folder "fonts" exist in place and the "ttf" files too.

Please, any idea what's happening? Is related to font in (Debian) server?

Here is the PHP file code. The HTML version is only the HTML embedded is this code.

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['debug' => true]);


$html = '
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<style>
@font-face
{
    font-family:"Open Sans";
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:normal;
    src:url("./fonts/OpenSans-Regular.eot"); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src:local( local("OpenSans-Regular"),
        url("./fonts/OpenSans-Regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), /* IE6-IE8 */
        url("./fonts/OpenSans-Regular.woff") format("woff"),  /* Modern Browsers */
        url("./fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf") format("truetype"),  /* Safari, Android, iOS */
        url("./fonts/OpenSans-Regular.svg#OpenSans") format("svg");  /* Legacy iOS */
}

@font-face
{
    font-family:"Open Sans Condensed Light";
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-stretch: ultra-condensed;
    src:url("./fonts/OpenSans-CondLight.eot"); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: local("OpenSans-CondLight"),
    url("./fonts/OpenSans-CondLight.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), /* IE6-IE8 */
    url("./fonts/OpenSans-CondLight.woff") format("woff"),  /* Modern Browsers */
    url("./fonts/OpenSans-CondLight.ttf") format("truetype"),  /* Safari, Android, iOS */
    url("./fonts/OpenSans-CondLight.svg#OpenSans") format("svg");  /* Legacy iOS */
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <p style="font-family:\'Open Sans\';">
        OpenSans<br/>
        HEX CODE    &#x2264;<br />
        HTML CODE   &#8804;<br />
        HTML ENTITY &le;<br />
        À Á Å å ā ă ñ Ñ ✓ ℃ ℉ 元 + − × ÷ = ≠ ¾ ⋜ ‰ ≏ ≢ ⊨ ∅ ∉ ∑ ∛ ∞ ∫ ≃ ⋚ ♳ 3  ∀(x, y ∈ A ∪ B; x ≠ y) x² − y² ≥ 0<br />
    </p></p>

    </br>
    <p style="font-family:\'Open Sans Condensed Light\';">
        OpenSans Condensed Light<br/>
        HEX CODE    &#x2264;<br />
        HTML CODE   &#8804;<br />
        HTML ENTITY &le;<br />
        À Á Å å ā ă ñ Ñ ✓ ℃ ℉ 元 + − × ÷ = ≠ ¾ ⋜ ‰ ≏ ≢ ⊨ ∅ ∉ ∑ ∛ ∞ ∫ ≃ ⋚ ♳ 3  ∀(x, y ∈ A ∪ B; x ≠ y) x² − y² ≥ 0<br />
    </p>

    </br>
    <p style="font-family:\'Arial\';">
        Arial<br/>
        HEX CODE    &#x2264;<br />
        HTML CODE   &#8804;<br />
        HTML ENTITY &le;<br />
        À Á Å å ā ă ñ Ñ ✓ ℃ ℉ 元 + − × ÷ = ≠ ¾ ⋜ ‰ ≏ ≢ ⊨ ∅ ∉ ∑ ∛ ∞ ∫ ≃ ⋚ ♳ 3  ∀(x, y ∈ A ∪ B; x ≠ y) x² − y² ≥ 0<br />
    </p>

    </br>
    <p style="font-family: \'Times New Roman\', Times, serif;">
        Times New Roman<br/>
        HEX CODE    &#x2264;<br />
        HTML CODE   &#8804;<br />
        HTML ENTITY &le;<br />
        À Á Å å ā ă ñ Ñ ✓ ℃ ℉ 元 + − × ÷ = ≠ ¾ ⋜ ‰ ≏ ≢ ⊨ ∅ ∉ ∑ ∛ ∞ ∫ ≃ ⋚ ♳ 3  ∀(x, y ∈ A ∪ B; x ≠ y) x² − y² ≥ 0<br />
    </p>


</body>
</html>
';

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

$mpdf->Output();
```

[image: HTML screenshot showing all characters with any font]
[image: mPDF PDF screenshot - Character "less or equal" is gone]

There is no difference if I add at beginning

```
$defaultConfig = (new Mpdf\Config\ConfigVariables())->getDefaults();
$fontDirs = $defaultConfig['fontDir'];

$defaultFontConfig = (new Mpdf\Config\FontVariables())->getDefaults();
$fontData = $defaultFontConfig['fontdata'];

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
    'fontDir' => array_merge($fontDirs, [
        __DIR__ . '/fonts',
    ]),
    'fontdata' => $fontData + [
        'open-sans' => [
            'R' => 'OpenSans-Regular.ttf',
            'C' => 'OpenSans-CondLight.ttf',
        ]
    ],
    'default_font' => 'open-sans' // Or even 'opensans' doesn't work
]);
```

Neverending story:
To test what's happening with that "unexistent" characters on mPDF, I remove any font reference in CSS, and same result. That characters doesn't appear in mPDF output. To try to guess where mPDF is getting open-sans fonts, I installed on my Debian server "open-sans" fonts (by default, only "Deja-Vú" fonts are installed). Same result. So, from where is getting mPDF that incomplete set of open-sans fonts???

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Sorry, I though was not necessary. I'ts very simple code, as you can see.

Comment: I doubt exactly this code example generates the PDF screenshotted above. The code example should be reproducible, you know. Where can the used font be obtained?

Comment: I was tried to use embedded TTF version, but MPDF has some problems processing base64 encoded text. So here you can dowload OpenSans (regular and condensed-light):

https://fonts2u.com/download/open-sans.font

https://fonts2u.com/download/open-sans-condensed-light.font